# Backbone - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'unbind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Using  Backbone 0.9.2 I am trying to unbind some element in the View but I get the following error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'unbind' of undefined

---

```
      console.log('+++ Kill: ', this);
        this.model.unbind( 'change', this.render, this ); // Unbind reference to the model
        this.options.parent.unbind( 'close:all', this.close, this ); // Unbind reference to the parent view     
        delete this.$el; // Delete the jQuery wrapped object variable
        delete this.el; // Delete the variable reference to this node
```

Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: which line caused the error? "this.model" or "this.options.parent"? output these two on console, check if they are defined

Comment: line this.model.unbind

Comment: This means, your view don't have a model, maybe it haven't been set or been removed somehow. you'd better check the logic before this process.

Comment: You are most likely using this.model in a callback and have forgot to bind that function to `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, clearly `this.model` is not what you think it is. Perhaps `this` isn't your view instance? In any case, just handle model events in your view's `initialize` like this:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this);
}
```

And you'll be fine as those will automatically get unbound during `remove` when it calls `stopListening`.